# Actionscript 3 - Creating a tween which moves object to the right

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, tween

I have a movieclip on the stage called bottomStick, and this is my Actionscript:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

Tween (bottomStick,"_x",Bounce.easeOut,100,500,4,false);
```

when I play this, it gives an error saying:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 8   1137: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected no more than 1.
```

why is it giving this error?

Answer (score 1):

Should be `new Tween(bottomStick,"_x",Bounce.easeOut,100,500,4,false);` Missing the `new` keyword in your post. Also as a side note, make sure `_x` is the correct property and not just `x`.